# Mid-2015 Macbook Pro Dented on Arrival

Tags: macbook-pro, damage

I was finally happy to be retiring my Early 2011 Macbook Pro, and upgrading to one of the newer force touch rMBP. But when the package arrived today, I noticed that it has a dent under the chassis.

I haven't used the laptop, or even turned it on, but the seller won't accept returns on eBay. Common sense would suggest getting in touch with Apple, but I'm not sure if this is covered under warranty.

What are my options right now?

Some pictures: 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the laptop is brand new then it should be covered under warranty by Apple for at least 12 months. I would definitely recommend getting in touch with them. You can lookup whether you're covered by warranty by entering in the laptop serial number [here](https://checkcoverage.apple.com/).

Even visit an Apple Store if there is one nearby you, they are usually more than happy to help.

Even though this is technically physical damage, it's due to no fault of your own, so it needs to be fixed.

I would also open a case with the seller through eBay, although they state they do not accept returns, if the dent wasn't photographed as part of the ad, or if it happened during shipping, it should be covered under the general eBay/PayPal returns policy.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, here in India. We have no concept of an Apple Store. Apple has third party partnership to service these laptops. They usually sell  for 30-40% premium. Helping me is a conflict of interest for these Apple authorised repair shops.

Let me try getting in touch with eBay

Comment: Ahh yes. My apologies. I would definitely open a case with eBay then. Maybe get in context with the seller first and see if they have any knowledge of the dent

Comment: @ThilakRao Don't let the seller on eBay get away with this